# How to display user details to my UserProfileViewController after I login using Alamofire swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am developing an app in which I have loginViewController and UserProfileViewController.After login, I would like to see my records on my UserProfileVC using NSUserDefaults.

Note: On my LoginVC I only have emailTextField and PasswordTextField. I would like to pass the firstname that came from my database and pass it to my UserProfileVC

This is my LoginVC:

```
  @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject){

    showLoadingMode (self)

    let email = emailTextField.text
    let password = passwordTextField.text
    let parameters = [
        "email" : email!,
        "password" : password!
    ]

    if (self.emailTextField.text == "" || self.passwordTextField.text == "" ) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign in Failed", message: "Please enter Email Address and Password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        actInd.stopAnimating()
    }
    else
    {

        let url = "http://localhost/alamofire/json-login.php"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        if let j = response.result.value {
            actInd.stopAnimating()
            var json = JSON(j)
            print(json)

            let result = json["result"].stringValue
```

//I would like to use NSUserDefaults here and send it to my UserProfileVC

```
            let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            prefs.setObject(json["firstname"], forKey: "firstname")
            prefs.setObject(email, forKey: "email")
            prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
            prefs.synchronize()

            if result == "1" {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoUserProfile", sender: self);

            }else{

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "Fail", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)

                alert.addAction(okAction)

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }

    }
    }}
```

Comment: If you want to pass data through your view controllers, you should use Segues.  With UserDefaults, you only have to use `let firstname = pref.getObject(forKey: "firstname") as? String` in your UserProfileVC. _it might help you [doc](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers#t=201609121240329740236)_

Comment: thank you for your reply. I already put that code on my UserProfileVC but still does not work. BTW, firstname is a field from my database that im trying to fetch and pass it thru NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Do you have a `User` model which you could instantiate with the response from `json-login.php` ? If so, you could for instance pass to `performSegueWithIdentifier("goToUserProfile", sender: user)` and in the `prepareForSegue(segue, sender)` get your `segue.destinationController` and set your user to it `segue.destinationController.user = sender`.

Comment: can you show me an example bout User Model and how to use it Sir.? Im pretty new in swift. Tho i know how to use prepareForSegue... thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So first you create a User model, that you could reuse in your app:

```
class User {
   var email = ""
   var firstname = ""

   init(email: String, firstname: String) {
       self.email = email
       self.firstname = firstname
   }
}
```

Now in your `loginAction()` of your `LoginVC`

```
// make stuff and request
if let j = response.result.value, let firstname = j["firstname"] as? String {
        actInd.stopAnimating()
        var json = JSON(j)
        let user = User(email: email, firstname: firstname)
        let result = json["result"] ?? "0" // if json["result"] doesn't exist it will be equal to "0"
        if result == "1" {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) { // It is recommended to do UI relative action inside the main thread.
                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoUserProfile", sender: user) // Here you send your user to be usable in prepareForSegue
            }
        }
} // Do other stuff
```

And in you `prepareForSegue` in your `LoginVC`

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoUserProfile" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationController
        destinationVC.user = sender // So you have to make a User attribute in your UserProfileVC
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I applied your code in my app but still it doesnt work. I think it does not recieved any data of firstname from database to save it to my User class. Im not sure tho.,..

Comment: In your original code, what was the result of `json["firstname"]` ?

Comment: In my original code, json["firstname"] is not really working. My problem is i dont know how to fetch a specific data from the database and put in my global variable and then make it available thru NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().

Comment: Actually, if you receive json from your request, you could quickly and easily parse it. So for instance `if let json = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {}`. You will have your json, basically you are getting your json as a Dictionnary where the keys are `String` and the values are `AnyObject`. Know you could try to get your firstname `if let firstname = json["firstname"] as? String {}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Zico. Your logic did works altho i applied your code in a different way..still its a big help bro. And i figured out whats wrong with my app...It's in my php file. I forgot to pass my data to my app in a right way. Anyways. Thanks bro.